# Limited In-App Purchases

Tags: android, timer, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I've implemented in-app billing to my app but I want to make it a little different. I want to create purchase for example: unlock this item for 2 months. When I want to end the purchased item license, I call my consumeItem(); method.

But where and how should I put this method, to be automatically consumed after 2 months after user has purchased it?

Comment: Maybe you should just use subscriptions? Just a thought...

Comment: yes, thats it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subscriptions may be a good idea. This way, user will definitely know that it is just a subscription and it can be immediately invalidated when the time comes.

Another good idea might be to use a server. You can store all the data about the purchases and information about the users. Then you can check the purchase status whenever you like using the beloew `Purchase Status API` https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html#overview and then you can disable users purchase status if the purchase was 2 months old.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation! I think that subscriptions are what do i need